# HP Pavilion Laptop 14-ec0007AX DDR4 SDRAM is better than DDR4

Tags: memory

i am planning to by [HP Pavilion Laptop 14-ec0007AX](https://www.hp.com/in-en/shop/hp-pavilion-laptop-14-ec0007ax-4j0x9pa.html) which has "**16 GB DDR4-3200 SDRAM (onboard)**".
My questions is DDR4 SDRAM is better than DDR4

when i searched on google most of the results related to SDRAM vs DDR or SDRAM vs DDR1/DDR2.. but couldn't find any article related to DDR4 SDRAM vs DDR4

Can anyone suggest whether DDR4 SDRAM is better or not ?

Comment: its probably just DDR4 that you can't take out

Comment: DDR4 is just a type of SDRAM, Many sites just do not add the SDRAM suffix.